# Add-advice :before org-edit-special

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, advice

I want to advise `org-edit-special` so that a function runs before Emacs enters `org-src-mode`. I am not particularly tied to `org-edit-special`. If there is a hook like `org-src-mode-hook` (but that triggers before `org-src-mode` runs, that would be perfect.

So I have the following code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp

(defun my-function ()
  (message "bingo!"))

(add-function :before (org-edit-special) #'(lambda () (my-function)))

#+END_SRC
```

When I `C-c C-c` this block, I get `user-error: No special environment to edit here`. Can you see the mistake?

Comment: Please say what you mean by "to work". What do you expect, and what do you see instead?

Comment: Drew thanks. I have added more to my post. Please let me know if you have additional questions. Best -Adam

Comment: `(org-edit-special)` is the result of calling the function `org-edit-special` - that's probably not what you want. Also, you should probably use `advice-add` (see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Named-Functions.html#Advising-Named-Functions)), not `add-function`.

Answer (score 1):

You port the `defadvice` approach from your own answer to nadvice.el like so:

```el
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(define-advice org-edit-special (:before (&optional arg) my-big-advice)
  (message "bingo!"))
#+END_SRC
```

`define-advice` is largely analogous to the older `defadvice`.

Comment: Thanks @phils - I find this topic extremely confusing, in particular because there appears to be no consensus in the documentation on how to get this done.  Can you speak to the advantages/disadvantages of each approach? What is the benefit of using nadvice.el versus the one I outlined above? And how about the approach that NickD mentioned, using `advice-add`? Also, in your code, if the optional args are not needed, do you still include the parentheses? I.e., `(define-advice org-edit-special (:before () my-big-advice) (message “bingo!”))`

Comment: I'll just add that as `nil` and `()` are the same thing in elisp, you could indeed use `()`.

Comment: Using nadvice.el tends to be strongly recommended nowadays.  Instances of old advice in Emacs core and in ELPA tend to get re-written.  It's probably best to get familiar with nadvice.  Using the `define-advice` macro is the easiest way to port old advice for the most part, and personally I think it's the most readable of the options provided by the nadvice library (certainly if you're familiar with the old advice library); so if it suits your purpose then I would suggest using it.  Entirely up to you, though.

Comment: @phils I just tested this out `(define-advice org-edit-special (:before () my-big-advice) (message "bingo!"))`. After evaluating, with point on an R src block, I ran `org-edit-special` and received the following error: `Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil (message "bingo!")), 1`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Adam I just meant that *if* it was valid to use `nil` then, in those cases, you could alternatively use `()` because the two things are the same.  My impression is that nadvice *requires* you to state the argument list, because it *uses* it -- so if it's not empty then you can't say that it is without breaking calls to the function.  In the case of `org-edit-special`, per the code in the answer, the appropriate value is `(&optional arg)`.

Comment: FWIW argument handling is an area where I personally think the old advice is much nicer than the new advice.

Comment: @phils What is the purpose of this new text `(&optional arg)`? Does this add some additional flexibility in the way that we advise functions that was not found in the `defadvice` pattern?

Comment: To be clear: `(&optional arg)` is the argument list for `org-edit-special`, the function which you are advising.  If you were advising something different, the argument list would likely be different.  Advice can mess with the arguments, so if you change that list you're changing the behaviour.  Specifying this was optional for `defadvice` but is required for `define-advice`.

Comment: This is why, when you set the argument list of `org-edit-special` to `nil` and something subsequently called that function with an argument, you ended up with an error "Wrong number of arguments".

Comment: @phils Does the argument list always have to match the function you are advising? If so, it seems like `defadvice` is a more compact way of getting at the same thing... unless adding the argument list lends some additional flexibility?

Comment: I believe the argument list you specify *replaces* the argument list for the original function (at least so far as callers are concerned), and so *yes* -- unless you are intentionally (and carefully) making changes to it, it needs to match the original.  It feels like an intentional design choice to have made that a required part of the new advice, and I also prefer the old system in this regard -- I wrote a lot of `defadvice`, and frequently manipulated argument values, but never once wanted to change the argument *list*.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the correct form:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp

(defun my-function ()
  (message "bingo!"))

(defadvice org-edit-special (before my-big-advice activate)
  (my-function))

#+END_SRC
```

And here is [a good tutorial](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AdvisingFunctions) on advising functions for anyone else who runs into this.

Looking at our revised code from left-to-right: `defadvice` is self-explanatory. `org-edit-special` is the function we are advising. `before` means we want our advice to happen first. `my-big-advice` is the name of our advice (we could have called this `foo-bar` if we wanted). And `activate` tells Emacs to make this work now.

Comment: `defadvice` is the old way of advising functions and although AFAIK not deprecated (yet?), it's probably a good idea to use the new mechanisms in new code. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-old-advice.html#Porting-old-advice).

Comment: @NickD This works for me without issue on Emacs 26.3. But if you would like to propose your own revised and updated code, please feel free.